# How to properly stringify XML to put in JSON body as part of CURL command

Tags: json, xml, bash, shell, curl

I'd like to add an XML file to my JSON request body in a CURL command. This is what I have right now

```
data=$(cat testdata.xml)
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "data": ''"$(echo $data)"''}' 'http://...'
```

However this sends `{ data: '$(echo $data)' } }` instead of actually fetching the file.

If I take out the outer single quotes around $(echo $data) like this:

```
data=$(cat testdata.xml)
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "data": '"$(echo $data)"'}' 'http://...'
```

Then I encounter error **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 10**

because the server is reading

```
'{ "data": <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> - <note> <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani</from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body> </note>}',
```

How do I fix this? Note that I do NOT want to convert to JSON first. I only want to send the stringified xml file in body.

Comment: Cramming stringified XML through the command line seems like the wrong approach.  Can you use the `-F` option to submit it as multipart/mime, reading from a file or a pipe?

Comment: `-d "{ data : \"$data\"}"`

Comment: @daniu, ...works only up until your data contains literal quotes, or newlines, or other content that needs to be escaped to be valid in a JSON string. And an XML document is *overwhelmingly* likely to contain newlines and quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to generate properly-escaped JSON in bash.

```
data=$(jq -Rs '{ "data": . }' <testdata.xml)
curl -X POST \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     -d "$data" \
     "$url"
```

---

If you don't have `jq` installed, you can use Python for the job, substituting the following for the line that used `jq`:

```
data=$(python -c 'import json, sys; json.dump({"data": sys.stdin.read()}, sys.stdout)' <testdata.xml)
```

Comment: to use this I would need to install jq?

Comment: Yes. bash does not have facilities for correct JSON handling built-in.

Comment: @b11, ...if you can't install `jq`, it's easy enough to call a Python interpreter from shell to do the job (as Python also has a correct JSON parsing/generation module); I've extended the answer to cover that.

Comment: Thank you for this, when I run the Python method I noticed that the xml being attached has newline characters `\n` and escape slash for strings. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: @b11, avoid it? It'd be incorrect escaping if you avoided it -- either the JSON document would no longer be valid, or reading the `data` string attribute in a JSON parser would no longer result in a correct, parsable XML document.

Comment: I see, so I have to handle that when I parse the XML on GET?

Comment: Since you're embedding it in JSON, you have two parsing passes -- one as JSON, the second as XML. When you read the value out from the JSON parsing pass, the `\n`s will be changed back to newlines, the `\"`s back to `"`s, etc. Or you can just do the sane thing and have your code on the far side accept direct post of an XML document instead of trying to embed it in JSON. Or you can actually have the client side know how to extract the content you want to post and submit *that* -- but the question doesn't provide enough details for me to provide an answer that helps you with it.

Comment: How would it be automatically converted to newlines if it is being sent as a string? This is what I get on GET `"data": {"data": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n - <note>\n       <to>Tove</to>\n       <from>Jani</from>\n       <heading>Reminder</heading>\n       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n   </note>"}`

Comment: Try `print(json.loads(posted_content)['data'])` -- you'll see the transformed content ready to pass to an XML parser. "How would it be converted to newlines?" -- that's err, what a JSON parser is *supposed to do*, since `\n` is a how a newline is represented in a JSON string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160804/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-b11).